# R problems with a count nrow inside of a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried to extract the nrow inside of a loop but it keep the same number of the last count for all interactions of the loop, the problem correspond to the lines

```
n1 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[1]],])  
n2 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[2]],])
```

This is part of a function:

```
Tab_Alpha <- suppressMessages(microbiome::alpha(Phyloseq, index = Index))
    colnames(Tab_Alpha)[1] <- Index 
    
    sd <- data.frame(sample_data(Phyloseq))
    sd[, Index] <- paste(Tab_Alpha[, Index])
    sd <- sd[, c(Index, Group)]
    Com_Group <- combn(unique(as.character(sd[, Group])), 2)
    
    Df <- c()
    Sum.Sq <- c()
    Mean.Sq <- c()
    F.value <- c() 
    Pr.F <- c() 
    group1 <- c()
    group2 <- c() 
    
    # The Loop !!!
    for(i in 1:ncol(Com_Group)){
        Gps <- c(Com_Group[1, i], Com_Group[2, i])
        Fsd <- dplyr::filter(sd, sd[, Group] %in% Gps)
        Aresult <- aov(Fsd[,Index] ~ Fsd[,Group])
        
        ar <- data.frame(list(summary(Aresult)[[1]]))
        
        colnames(ar) <- paste(c("Df", "Sum.Sq", "Mean.Sq", "F.value", "Pr.F"))
        ar <- ar[-c(2), ]
        
        
        
        Df <- rbind(Df, ar[, "Df"])
        Sum.Sq <- rbind(Sum.Sq, ar[, "Sum.Sq"])
        Mean.Sq <- rbind(Mean.Sq, ar[, "Mean.Sq"])
        F.value <- rbind(F.value, ar[, "F.value"])
        Pr.F <- rbind(Pr.F, ar[, "Pr.F"])
        group1 <- rbind(group1, Gps[[1]])
        group2 <- rbind(group2, Gps[[2]])
        
        n1 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[1]],])   # The Problem !!!
        n2 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[2]],])   # The Problem !!!
        
    }
    
    # Code 
    p.signif = c(rep('',length(Pr.F)))
    p.signif[Pr.F >  0.05]  <-'ns'
    p.signif[Pr.F <= 0.05]  <-'.'
    p.signif[Pr.F <= 0.01]  <-'*'
    p.signif[Pr.F <= 0.001] <-'**'
    p.signif[Pr.F <= 0]     <-'***'
    #0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1      
    
    AnovaR <- data.frame(Group, Index, n1, n2, Df, Sum.Sq, Mean.Sq, F.value, Pr.F, group1, group2, p.signif)
```

In the final data.frame AnovaR I add n1 and n2 to give the number of element that correspond to one group based on Gps[[1]] and the second based on Gps[[2]] in each comparison, but it print only the last count for all interactions, I mean, if I have 3 groups (Illumina (n=85), Pyro454 (n=154) and Sanger (n=41)) it must print how many nrow are in each groups, but in the next data frame only appear 85 for n1 and 154 for n2 that correspond to last interaction of Illumina (85) and Pyro454 (154)

```
   Group   Index n1  n2 Df      Sum.Sq     Mean.Sq     F.value       Pr(>F)   group1   group2 p.signif
1 SeqTech shannon 85 154  1 0.001703502 0.001703502  0.02169554 8.831391e-01   Sanger Illumina       ns
2 SeqTech shannon 85 154  1 3.646070790 3.646070790 28.68863997 2.403115e-07   Sanger  Pyro454       **
3 SeqTech shannon 85 154  1 6.459171438 6.459171438 66.22950059 2.269616e-14 Illumina  Pyro454       **
```

but it must be

```
    Group   Index n1  n2 ....   n1       n2
1 SeqTech shannon 41  85 .... Sanger   Illumina 
2 SeqTech shannon 41 154 .... Sanger   Pyro454
3 SeqTech shannon 85 154 .... Illumina Pyro454
```

I tried to add a empty variables for n1 and n2 outside of the for loop (before of the loop )

```
n1 <- c()
n2 <- c()
```

and then add it to AnovaR data.frame, but it keep the same result.

however if I use a print inside of the loop it works well !!

```
.......... code before 

        n1 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[1]],])
        n2 <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[2]],])
        print(n1)
        print(n2)

code after ...............
```

the results is :

```
myfunction(enterotype, Group = "SeqTech", Index = "shannon")
[1] 41      # first interaction 
[1] 85      # first interaction
[1] 41      # second interaction
[1] 154     # second interaction
[1] 85      # third interaction
[1] 154     # third interaction
```

how can I fix just the n1 and n2 variables!

By the way I'm using Anova statistics.

Comment: compared to others, i.e. `group1, `group2` etc which does `rbind` inside the loop, where as `n1` and `n2` are created just inside the loop and it gets replaced in each iteration.  So, what you return is from the last iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix based on the code showed will be the same as the one used for initialization of 'group1', 'group2' etc. i.e. create an empty vector for 'n1', 'n2' and `rbind` or `c`

```
# // initialize outside
n1 <- c()
n2 <- c()
```

Then inside the loop do

```
n1 <- c(n1, nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[1]],]))
n2 <- c(n2, nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[2]],]))
```

These are the only values that were not initialized and not `rbind`ed within the loop, thus it gets replaced on each iteration returning the value from the last iteration

---

This kind of initialization i.e. empty vector is mostly done when we don't know the length beforehand.  Here, it would be the number of columns of 'Com_Group'.  So, all of the objects could be initialized similar to

```
 n1 <- numeric(ncol(Com_Group))
 n2 <- numeric(ncol(Com_group))
```

Then inside the `for` loop, use the index for assignment to that specific element

```
n1[i] <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[1]],])
n2[i] <- nrow(Fsd[Fsd[, Group] == Gps[[2]],])
```